# Getting selected LinkButton in ListView ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which contains a column where I need to put two link buttons - Open and Download to open and download a server file respectively. I have an id column for each row of the list view. I have set the DataKeyNames property of listview to "ID" and verified that DataKeys get populated with the row values. On clicking a particular link button I need the selected ID to determine the link of the server file corresponding to that row. I have added the linkButton_click event but when I try to access SelectedDataKey inside the handler it remains null. How can I get the ID inside the click handler of the link button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
 protected void ConferencesListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int _Id;
        int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out _Id);
        if (e.CommandName == "View")
        {
        }
    }
```

and in designer:

```
 <asp:LinkButton  ID="ViewLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [`ListView.ItemCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and get the `DataKeys` as below

```
  protected void EmployeesListView_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "AddToList"))
    {
      // Verify that the employee ID is not already in the list. If not, add the
      // employee to the list.
      ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
      string employeeID = 
        EmployeesListView.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();

      if (SelectedEmployeesListBox.Items.FindByValue(employeeID) == null)
      {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), employeeID);
        SelectedEmployeesListBox.Items.Add(item);
      }
    }
  }
```

Above example taken directly from the MSDN, you better check how the aspx markup and the code behind need to be change as the example given in the documentation link provided above.